# jQMobile defaultPageTransition doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, default

I'm using `jQMobile` for my Web application. i'm using the latest version 1.1.1.

i try to set by default the `$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";`

But it's doesn't work, and when i change the version of `jQMobile` to `jquery.mobile-1.0b2` it's work fine.

Any suggestion ?

Code :

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";
});
```

Comment: Works fine here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/data-attributes.html. I tried setting `$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";` through Chrome dev tools and transitions became sliding transitions

Answer (score 12):

Move the code into its own file, say "custom-init.js".

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() { 
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";
});
```

In your script imports, include "custom-init.js" after you include jQuery, but before you include jQuery Mobile:

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="custom-init.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

That should get it working for you.

Comment: I have successfully used it. But if I want to go back to the main page? For example in this case : http://pastebin.com/FUzjQnjX